# Post-hoc tests of interaction for a negative binomial regression with survey weights?

Tags: r, negative-binomial-distribution, post-hoc, lsmeans, survey-weights

I ran a negative binomial regression with survey weights using the R package `survey` and the function `svyglm()` and observed a significant interaction effect (woohoo!). Now I want to understand the interaction using post-hoc tests. I tried using the packages `emmeans` but I got an error. Any ideas how do this kind of thing (preferably in R, though manually/quasi-manually or another software system is good too)? Below is a MWE.

```
install.packages(c("survey", "emmeans"))
library(survey)
library(emmeans)

# Simulating some data
set.seed(123)
n <- 200
df <- data.frame(
  y = rpois(n, lambda = 2), # Simulated count data
  predictor1 = factor(sample(c("A", "B", "C"), n, replace = TRUE)),
  predictor2 = factor(sample(c("X", "Y"), n, replace = TRUE)),
  weights = runif(n, 0.5, 2),  # Simulated weights
  cluster = factor(rep(1:20, each = 10)), # Simulated cluster ID
  strata = factor(rep(1:4, each = 50)) # Simulated strata
)

# Creating survey design
des <- svydesign(ids = ~cluster, strata = ~strata, weights = ~weights, data = df)

# Fit model
model <- svyglm(response ~ predictor1 * predictor2, design = design, family = quasipoisson())

# Estimate marginal means for the interaction terms
emm_interaction <- emmeans(model, ~ predictor1 * predictor2)

# Pairwise comparisons for interaction terms
pairs_interaction <- pairs(emm_interaction)

# Summary of the comparisons
summary(pairs_interaction)
```

When I execute `emm_interaction <- emmeans(model, ~ predictor1 * predictor2)` I get the following error message.

```
Error in ref_grid(object, ...) : We are unable to reconstruct the data.
The variables needed are:
    predictor1 predictor2
Are any of these actually constants? (specify via 'params = ')
 Try re-running with 'data = "<name of dataset>"'
```

Comment: This seems like a coding/programming question rather than a question about statistics _per se_ so it is off-topic on this site. I'll note that `svyglm()` models have ["Group A" support](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/models.html#A), for which "Some [models] may require `data` in the call."

Comment: @EdM That makes sense. What do people normally do in this case? Delete the post and repost to overflow?

Comment: @EdM I added `data=data` to `emm_interaction <- emmeans(model, ~ predictor1 * predictor2)` and it seems to work. But is emmeans using the weighted data in this call? Any idea how I can verify?

Comment: I don't know. Try editing to ask that specific question, if you can't glean that from the source code. Not clear whether that might be considered too coding-specific for this site, but if so you can ask on Stack Overflow. I think that Russ Lenth checks in on both sites.

Comment: Looks like the `phia` package does post-hoc tests based on `svyglm` without errors. Perhaps I could weight a toy dataset manually and compare the results from that dataset and `glm.nb` and `emmeans` with those obtained from the unweighted dataset and `survey` and `phia`.